# How to create/update an array using input checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, checkbox

In my view I am iterating through a collection of `Customers` called `@colleagues` and displaying them in a list as checkbox inputs like so:

```
<ol>
  <% @colleagues.each do |c|%>
    <li>
       <input type="checkbox">
           <%= c.full_name %>
           <%= c.id %>
       </input>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ol>
```

What I wish to do is collect each checked/selected name in an array, which, on pushing of a button, will be sent to my controller. My question is, **how can I create a dynamic array in javascript so that a colleague's `id` is added to the array or removed when unchecked?**

Thanks

Comment: You can do it without JS, but using Rails form. Will it work for you? Or you insist us to give you JS solution ? let me know, then I can probably help you

Comment: FYI, input is void element, your HTML markup as no meaning. Now to send checkboxes to server, set value and name attribute and [serialize them](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) (or [serializeArray](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/))or use a `form` to wrap them

Comment: @ArupRakshit I think I need to use JS because I need to use AJAX to send info back and forth between the controller without losing the view, as it's not sent to the controller on form submit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this example can help you:

```
<ul id="featuresOptions" class="options" style="display: block;">
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="Apartment" value="6"> Apartment</label></li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="House" value="7"> House</label></li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="Lot" value="8"> Lot</label></li>
    <li><button class="button" id="featuresButton">Filter</button></li>
</ul>

$(document).on('click', "#featuresButton", function() {
    var formData = [];
    $("#featuresOptions li input").each(function(e) {
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
            formData.push($(this).val());
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: this is quite useful thank you. The line $(this).val(); is retrieving the value specified within the input tags, but the value I want is the id, is there a way I can set an input's value to be the @colleague's id?

Comment: Yes like `<input type="checkbox" value="<%= c.id %>"><%= c.full_name %></input>`
BTW if you are sticking with my answer, please tick it as ;)

Comment: brilliant, I can't believe I couldn't think of that myself! Thanks